# Magento 2.3: Re-save all products programatically

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, programmatically

#### I need to re-save all products programatically without modifying any attribute. **(Only re-save)**

**How to do that ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom script on the root of Magento.

> magentoroot/saveallproduct.php

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$productcollection = $productCollectionFactory->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();

foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
    $productId = $product->getId();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $product->load($productId);
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that web root scripts are a security risk as can be triggered by the browser. Ideally this should written as a shell script or dev only and removed immediately after use.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if is there a fastest way to do it? I have more than 35,000 products in 4 different store views, and it takes a long time.